# How do you add a menu to a vs code extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I can't find any information on creating a menu in a vs code extension. Is this possible? Are there examples somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

It's currently not possible.  It is [a requested feature](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/3192), though.

---

Edit

With the release of Version 1.3, there are now [menu Contribution Points](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/extension-points#_contributesmenus).